# Adding a Tap Gesture Recognizer to TableViewCell.swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view cell with an image that I have attached a Tap Gesture Recognizer to.

Image of prototype TableViewCell in Table View with two labels and an image. At the top there is the Tap Gesture Recognizer logo:

[image]

When I attempt to ctrl and drag the Tap Gesture Recognizer to the `TableViewCellController`, `TableViewCell` files or any other file, it won't let me.

However, on my other view that isn't a table view, I can get this to work fine. I'm new to Swift. Would anyone know why this is happening, and what I can do to help it (I know I *could* use a button instead, but I wouldn't learn anything from that)?

Both the `TableViewCell` and `TableViewCellController` files have their default code.

**Edit**: What I want is for the user to be able to tap the image to add +1 to a Int property in the class in the table cell. One of the UILabels in the class, and the cell, is updated. This is the kind of behaviour I can achieve without problem in a regular view and want to achieve in the table view.

Comment: do you need swap cell menu?

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper I'm not sure. I don't know what that would achieve. In tapping the image it would add +1 to a Int property in the class in the table cell.

Comment: @Weirdali looks like you just need a button with an image on it. Just create a custom cell with your button and connect your button outlet to the custom cell

Answer (score 9):

For `UITableViewCell` you cannot add a `UITapgesture` to it via storyboard because it is just a prototype cell unlike others. If you really want to do that you can do it programatically in the delegate like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "SomeMethod")
    cell.myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    return cell
}
```

But i can't find out why you want to do that. If you just want to do something or call some function when cell is tapped, you should be using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("cell at #\(indexPath.row) is selected!")
}
```

Comment: You say I can't add a UITapGesture to a prototype cell - but it won't always be a prototype cell? I want to add functionality to table cells in the same way that an individual view would work - and this involves tapping on certain parts of the cell, not the whole thing. So it doesn't seem like didSelectRowAtIndexPath would do what I want. Sorry if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: Don't you mean `return cell` instead of `return UITableViewCell()` ?

Comment: @Weirdali at storyboard, `UITableViewCell` will be a prototype as it could potentially be thousands or even millions of row so it is being reuse instead of creating a new one everytime. If you want to add to certain views, you could modify the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I have updated it for you.